# Why does it appear that this string is stored inline by value in an explicit layout class or struct?

Tags: c#, pointers, cil, unsafe

I have been doing some extremely unsafe and slightly useless messing with the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` MSIL package that allows you to do a lot of things with pointers you can't in C#. I created an extension method that returns a `ref byte`, with that byte being the start of the Method Table pointer at the start of the object, which allows you to use any object in a fixed statement, taking a byte pointer to the start of the object:

```
public static unsafe ref byte GetPinnableReference(this object obj)
{
    return ref *(byte*)*(void**)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref obj);
}
```

I then decided to test it, using this code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0)]
public class Foo
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public string Name = "THIS IS A STRING";
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0)]
public struct Bar
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public string Name;
}
```

And then in the method

```
        var foo = new Foo();
        //var foo = new Bar { Name = "THIS IS A STRING" };

        fixed (byte* objPtr = foo)
        {
            char* stringPtr = (char*)(objPtr + (foo is Foo ?  : 12));

            for (var i = 0; i < foo.Name.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(*(stringPtr + i /* Char offset */));
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

The really weird thing about this is that this successfully prints "THIS IS A STRING"? The code works like this:

1. Get a byte pointer, `objPtr`, to the very start of the object
2. Add 16 to get to the actual data
3. Add another 16 to get past the string header to the string's actual data
4. Add 4 to skip the first 4 bytes of the string, which are the `int` `_stringLength` (exposed to us as `Length` property)
5. Interpret the result as a char pointer

EDIT: Important point - when switching `foo` to type `Bar`, I only add 12 rather than 36 bytes on (36 = 16 + 16 + 4). Why does it only have 8 bytes of header in the struct rather than 32 in the class? It would make sense that the struct has a smaller header (no syncblk i believe), but then why doesn't the string still have a 16 byte head? I would expect the offset to be 8 + 16 + 4 (28) rather than just 8 + 4 (12)
However, this assumption makes a big flaw. It assumes the string is stored inline inside the `class/struct`. However, strings are reference types and only a reference to them is stored inside the object from my knowledge. Particularly, I thought reference types can *only* be put on the heap - and as this struct is a local variable I thought it was on the stack. If it wasn't, the code would surely look something more like this to get the `stringPtr`

```
byte** stringRefptr = objPtr + 16;
char* stringPtr = (char*)(*stringRefPtr + 20);
```

where you take the string reference as a `byte**` and then use it to get to the chars. And this still wouldn't make sense if the string internally was a `char[]` (I'm not sure if it is)

So why does this work, and print the string, even though it mistakenly assumes string is stored inline, when string is a reference type?

NOTE: Requires .NET Core 2.0+ with `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` nuGet package, and C# 7.3+.

Comment: Did you run this in release mode? I get a garbled string in release mode but it works in debug.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen works fine for me when running in release. Make sure it's 100% 64 bit tho - the method table pointer and syncblk are different sizes in 32 bit

Comment: I am using 64 bit. Looking at the code in WinDbg the string is clearly on the heap as expected. Still trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: `So why does this work, and print the string, even though it mistakenly assumes string is stored inline, when string is a reference type?` Sometimes, we bring faulty assumptions to a problem. Our assumptions are wrong, and yet the behaviour we see is consistent with our faulty assumptions. This might mean one of two things. a) Our faulty assumptions are in fact correct. b) Our faulty assumptions are in fact wrong, and yet it works for some reason _other than_ our faulty assumption.

Comment: @PetSerAl i assumed it returns a ref to the start of the syncblk of the object,

Comment: @PetSerAl the Foo object

Comment: Unsafe.AsPointer returns a pointer to an object reference ( as opposed to a ref to an object reference ). That's equivalent to a void** to the object data itself

Comment: OK, I understand where error in my understanding of `Unsafe.AsPointer` was. I tried [your code with little change](https://gist.github.com/PetSerAl/5f1d64014ce300fcea0b2ba1fcb299fc) (added loop over the test) and it does not print the string all the times. Does your code reliably print the string even if you run the test multiple times in the same process?

Comment: @PetSerAl that's a good point. I've ran it many times but each have been once per process. When I can test it I'll get back to you

Answer (score -1):

Because strings are indeed stored inline. The problem with your assumption is that strings are not normal objects but handled as a special case by the CLR (probably for performance reasons).

And as for the objects, since the string is the only member this would naturally be the most efficient way to allocate the memory. Try adding more members after your string member and your code would break.

Here’s a few references in how strings are stored in the CLR

https://mattwarren.org/2016/05/31/Strings-and-the-CLR-a-Special-Relationship/

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/

Edit: I didn’t check, but I believe your reasoning behind the offsets is off. 36 = 24 (size of object) + 8 (string header?) + 4 (size of int) while for the struct the24 bytes becomes 0 as it has no header.

Comment: Yes, I know that part, but strings are still reference types. Even though the string data is inline, surely in my struct/class it should just be a pointer

Comment: Yes, but the object can store one pointer inline AFAIK. This means that if you inspect those bytes it should be a pointer to the next object (the string). In most cases the heap would probably have space just after. As I said, try adding more members to the class and the code will break.